# How to show page preloader only once

Tags: javascript, css, preloader

Good afternoon,
I'm trying to place page preloader into my webpage. But I can't set it to show only once, when I'm entering the page. Every time, when I click "home" button, it appears again. Could anyone help me with that please?

HTML:

```
<div id="loader-wrapper">
    <div id="loader"></div>

    <div class="loader-section section-left"></div>
    <div class="loader-section section-right"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('body').addClass('loaded');
        $('h1').css('color','#222222');
    }, 3000);

});
```

CSS:

```
#loader {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: white;

    -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 5+ */
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */

    z-index: 1001;
}

    #loader:before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 5px;
        right: 5px;
        bottom: 5px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 3px solid transparent;
        border-top-color: gray;

        -webkit-animation: spin 3s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 5+ */
        animation: spin 3s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
    }

    #loader:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 15px;
        left: 15px;
        right: 15px;
        bottom: 15px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 3px solid transparent;
        border-top-color: white;

        -webkit-animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 5+ */
          animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes spin {
        0%   { 
            -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
            -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);  /* IE 9 */
            transform: rotate(0deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
        }
        100% {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
            -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);  /* IE 9 */
            transform: rotate(360deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
        }
    }
    @keyframes spin {
        0%   { 
            -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
            -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);  /* IE 9 */
            transform: rotate(0deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
        }
        100% {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
            -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);  /* IE 9 */
            transform: rotate(360deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you press 'home' button, you reload page, i guess, so that's expected behavior. However, you can use cookies, and show preloader only on first visit...

Comment: I know.. That's why I am asking here how to solve it... 
Well, I have no idea how to use cookies that way..:(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15935900/how-to-show-page-preloader-only-once-while-entering-through-domain-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (!$.cookie('loaded')) {
  // show preloader
  // your code
  // create cookie
  $.cookie('loaded', true, {expires: 365});
}
```

or try this:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {

    if ($.cookie('preloader'))
    {
        $('#loader-wrapper').hide();
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('body').addClass('loaded');
            $('h1').css('color','#222222');
        }, 3000);

        // and now we create 1 year cookie
        $.cookie('preloader', true, {path: '/', expire: 365});
    }
});
```

Download from here JavaScript API for handling cookies: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie
Include after jquery jquery.cookie.js

Comment: I've tried both scripts, but they didn't work..:/ now when I load the page, it doesn't even stop "preloading"..

Comment: @HynekŠ.Add jquery.cookie.js

Comment: I've added jquery.cookie.js but still the same problem. It doesn't even matter which of those codes I am trying, but preloader never stops loading..:/

Comment: Ok, it works for me now too! Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Welcome! I'm glad it worked. :) Sorry I couldn't explain better.